# Multiple GPUs, Multiple Monitors, GPU seems ineffective

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, gpu, amd-radeon

I have three GPUs.  My onboard GPU that is integrated into CPU, and two AMD Radeon RX550 series cards.  I have three monitors, two monitors plugged into the second AMD, and one into the first AMD.

But, even though all monitors work, everything seems to hit the first GPU.
[image: AMD Performance Metrics]

It might be that Windows doesn't see both cards?

[image: Windows 10 Graphics Settings]

Device Manager says that Graphic Settings are confused:
[image: Device Manager]

Or maybe it's only focusing the active monitor, and the others are just considered idle, and to get the most I'd have to somehow bridge my GPU's (don't think these even support that).

I run into issues where I have to lower my graphics settings within games ... games that my cards should be more than capable of handling.

My drivers are up-to-date:

[image: Driver Status]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "everything seems to hit the first GPU" - have you tried to move some windows from the monitor(s) served by the first GPU to the other monitors?

Comment: @harrymc yes ... "maybe it's only focusing the active monitor, and the others are just considered idle" ... because just moving the mouse cursor to another window flips it.  It's like it only can use one at a time.

Comment: Do you mean that windows move by themselves into the active monitor? If not, please give a better description in your post of the phenomenon.

Comment: @harrymc No, and I don't understand how you'd think that from what I've said, so I don't know what you want me to edit.

Answer (score 0):

100% utilization on GPU1 tells me that you're gaming? If so then that's expected. There's no reason for GPU2 to ramp up if GPU1 is the only one being used.

Try this, play a YouTube video on each monitor and see if those percentages change.

As far as I can tell, crossfire is not supported on the RX 550 so "bridging" those GPUs is not possible. https://www.gpumag.com/amd-crossfire/

You can follow the instructions here to double-check that crossfire is not an option; https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/faq/dh-018

Overall, AMD crossfire and Nvidia SLI are abandoned technologies. Sadly, RX 5xx series has crossfire support but you have chosen the model which is an exception.